# How to change view of bootstrap-datetimepicker to show days when the format includes time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using **bootstrap-datetimepicker** to allow users to filter dashboard content by date. The datepicker is formatted as ***'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'***, it needs to be in this format.

The problem is when I click on the element, the view mode is showing a time selector. I need it to show the days instead.

I tried the available functions in the docs, I couldn't find one that works. Anyone has any suggestion?

**This is what I currently get:**
[image]

**But I want it to be this instead:**
[image]

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: I am using the bootstrap-datetimepicker by http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Provide the code you are using.

Comment: Try viewMode: 'months'. Sorry I meant viewMode: 'days'

Comment: Use format to tell the `datepicker` that how you like it to be formatted like `format: 'L'`. Hope, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was to maybe somehow switch between formats when the datepicker popup gets opened, but that’s likely going to be messy, and might easily lead to additional problems I suppose.

I guess simply hiding the controls you don’t need here via CSS might be your best option.

Now the HTML structure is a bit tricky to debug, because the relevant elements get removed from the DOM again most of the time when you try to inspect this in dev tools, but basically this renders as an unordered list using the class `list-unstyled` (simply going with the first example on the page you mentioned here), and each of those collapsible panels is an item inside that list. So

```
.list-unstyled li:not(:first-child) { display: none; }
```

seems to basically get the job done here.

If you only need this for a particular date picker out of multiple on a page, you might need to get a bit more specific with the selector; but since this seems to append the extra HTML elements directly inside the container you initialize the date picker on, using the descendant selector that should also be quite easy.